# How to read min/max variables from a text file?

Tags: c, file-io, input, io, scanf

I want to be able to set a min/max range and use it to check valid/invalid inputs while reading values from a file.

My min and max values in the first line are *1* and *10*, respectively. This is my text file to be tested (*num.txt*):

```
1 10
2 
4
5
```

In this program, I want to use `fscanf(stdin , ...)`:

```
fscanf( stdin, "%d%c", &num, &c );
```

How can I read the first line and check it for the min and max values and then continue reading the following lines?

Comment: From the num.txt. I want to set 1 10 to be my min/max. Then i'm going to check if #'s 2,4,5 are in between the MAX/MIN range set from the file.

Comment: I  got therefore posted an answer .

Comment: I posted mine answer too, I think you want both to know how to loop and use input redirection `program < num.txt` when calling it from console right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardcoding the file name in program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    int min, max;

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen( "num.txt", "r");

    if( fscanf( fp,"%d %d", &min, &max) != 2) // Read Min/MAX from file
        return -1; // wrong input file

    int val;
    while( fscanf( fp, "%d", &val) == 1 ) //check if new values in range
        if(val<min || val>max)
            printf( "Invalid INPUT: Value %d is not in (%d, %d) range", val, min, max);

    fclose( fp);
    return 0;
}
```

using input redirection of console shell

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    int min, max;

    if( fscanf( stdin,"%d %d", &min, &max) != 2) // Read Min/MAX from file
        return -1; // wrong input file

    int val;
    while( fscanf( stdin, "%d", &val) == 1 ) //check if new values in range
        if(val<min || val>max)
            printf( "Invalid INPUT: Value %d is not in (%d, %d) range", val, min, max);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When you do the while loop is it not looking at the first line of the file anymore. Thanks for the help

Comment: no problem !:) don't forget to accept the answer :) and wellcome to Stackoverflow :)

Comment: I will, but so is the the while loop not looking at the first line of the file anymore or does it see 1 10

Comment: The 1 10 is stored in variables min,max then the file "cursor" is already moved ahead and you will just see following values (every time you read a value the file "cursor" will advance).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Be very careful with your validation checks. As it sits, you could easily have just a single value on the first line, or a single value and a letter and it would still execute without complaining.

Comment: `while( fscanf( stdin, "%d", &val) != EOF )` begins an infinite loop should the input be non-numeric.  Better to use something like `while( fscanf( stdin, "%d", &val) == 1)`

Answer (score 3):

To read from a file you can do this -

```
 FILE *fp;
 fp=fopen("num.txt","r");              // check its return .
 fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&min,&max);
```

To keep reading further values you can use `fscanf` in a loop-

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%d",&variable)==1){  // on success fscanf return 1 here, till fscanf is successful loop will iterate
   // do you operations 
   }
```

Comment: I'm using program.o < num.txt to open the file. Also I understand I can use fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&min,&max); but I need to continue reading the file

Comment: @user5343207  Ok I get it now .Sorry for that .I updates my answer .